# JunOS iBGP and return paths odd behaviour

Tags: routing, router, bgp, juniper, juniper-junos

I've got a somewhat basic iBGP configuration with a routing instance **"global"** between two Juniper vSRX's - each Juniper vSRX has an uplink of its own from a different transit provider with a default route. The iBGP *within* the routing instance **"global"** works as expected, failing over nicely between the two.

However, when adding another routing instance into play, let's say **"client-1"** with a default route with a next-table of **"global.inet.0"** traffic does not flow when ingressing or egressing through the other vSRX.

Outbound is sort of fine, because I can put equal preference on the routes out via iBGP and the local transit, but obviously inbound is beyond my control - so in the example below if Transit 2 was my inbound route 1.2.3.4 would not be pingable but 1.2.3.5 would be.

[image: Example]

I've checked the basics such as host-inbound stanzas on the security zones, global ping is enabled, etc.

When pinging 1.2.3.4 and Transit 2 is the inbound route in the example, vSRX 1 can see the ping packets arriving (the correct place) but no ICMP response is given:

```
vsrx2# run show security flow session destination-prefix 1.2.3.4/32    
Session ID: 289005, Policy name: self-traffic-policy/1, Timeout: 6, Valid
  In: home.ip/2103 --> 1.2.3.4/31;icmp, Conn Tag: 0x0, If: ge-0/0/2.203, Pkts: 1, Bytes: 60, 
  Out: 1.2.3.4/31 --> home.ip/2103;icmp, Conn Tag: 0x0, If: .local..7, Pkts: 0, Bytes: 0, 
Total sessions: 1
```

Interestingly, a loopback on vSRX 1 in this case that sits in the **"global"** routing instance, with the route in via Transit 2 is reachable.

Any ideas why the ping packets arrive in the right place, but do not get a response?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Outbound traffic is jumping between isolated routing-instances with your `next-table` policy - do you have a return route to 1.2.3.0/26 in `inet.0` in `vsrx2` (and vice-versa) with a `next-table client-1.inet.0`?  Do you have a more specific route for 1.2.3.4 on `vsrx2` with a next-hop of `vsrx1`?

Otherwise, I don't think this is going to work - specifically for the SRX interface addresses - if I'm not mistaken, return traffic via `vsrx2` is going to see a static route for `1.2.3.0/26` with a next-table of `client-1.inet.0` and try and egress locally (which will break the flow).

I'm a bit confused by your flow output on `vsrx2` though - according to your diagram, `1.2.3.4` is on `vsrx1`, but the flow output says that it's from `vsrx2` and shows a return interface of `local` (suggesting that the destination address 1.2.3.4 is an IP owned by `vsrx2`) - I would expect to be seeing the logical interface between `vsrx2` and `vsrx1` instead?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, there are return routes to pull the subnet into the correct routing instance with instance-import's. 1.2.3.0/26 has a route to the interface (which maps to the client-1 instance). I'm not sure it is possible to add a more specific route, because I can't think of what to reference the next-hop / next-table as? Also, adding that would mean if it was flipped and the inbound route is over the other transit, I'd have the same problem.

Comment: I've also just tried to debug by bringing the interface into the "global" routing instance - it has the same problem. The active route is over vsrx1, pinging the address on vsrx1 is fine, but pinging the vsrx2 address isn't fine.

It does work if I bring the "client-1" interface into the same security zone as the transit / iBGP. The security policies and zones are identical on both vSRX's.

Comment: Can you update the question and attach the flow session from both nodes when you have the active route over vsrx1 and try to ping the interface address on vsrx2?